# How to use the ProGuard in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, proguard

This is my first project in Android Studio, and the code of my apps are not obfuscated.
Im using this configuration in build.gradle file:
[image]

I'm using the Build > Generate Signed APK... with the Run Proguard checked.
And, when I have tested using the Apk_OneClick.v4.2, my code is completly easy to read:

[image]

Please, help-me. :(

Comment: show your proguard rules defined in text file for obfuscate code.

Comment: How to check whether the app is obfuscated or not?

Comment: @VVB by reverse engeneering APK-file I guess :D

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You're probably not actually signing the release build of the APK via the signing wizard. You can either build the release APK from the command line with the command:

```
./gradlew assembleRelease
```

or you can choose the release variant from the **Build Variants** view and build it from the GUI:

[image: IDE main window showing Build Variants]

Comment: Great! I have tested changing the debug to runProguard true and works perfectly. Now I read your reply, and works!!!! Great man! Thank you.

Comment: Oops, I accidentally put "assembleDebug" instead of "assembleRelease" in my command-line instructions. I fixed my answer.

Comment: What is the path of the .apk file that is exported via command line?

Answer (score 50):

You can configure your build.gradle file for proguard implementation. It can be at module level or the project level.

```
 buildTypes {

    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'

    }

}
```

The configuration shown is for debug level but you can write you own build flavors like shown below inside buildTypes:

```
    myproductionbuild{
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
```

Better to have your debug with `minifyEnabled false` and productionbuild and other builds as `minifyEnabled true`.

Copy your proguard-rules.txt file in the root of your module or project folder like

`$YOUR_PROJECT_DIR\YoutProject\yourmodule\proguard-rules.txt`

You can change the name of your file as you want. After configuration use one of the three options available to generate your build as per the buildType

1. Go to gradle task in right panel and search for `assembleRelease/assemble(#your_defined_buildtype)` under module tasks
2. Go to Build Variant in Left Panel and select the build from drop down
3. Go to project root directory in File Explorer and open cmd/terminal and run

Linux `./gradlew assembleRelease or assemble(#your_defined_buildtype)`

Windows  `gradlew assembleRelease  or  assemble(#your_defined_buildtype)`

You can find apk in your module/build directory.

More about the configuration and proguard files location is available at the link

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Running-ProGuard

Comment: Where I can say to use the myproductionbuild?

Comment: ya, you are correct :) you can see the same in the build Variant tab on left side panel.

Comment: But apk don't have obfuscate... :(

Comment: have you written the configuration in proguard-rule.txt see some examples over here http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/examples.html

Comment: Im having Gradle DSL method runProguard() not found.

Comment: runProguard is deprecated. Instead of using runProguard in your gradle file, try using minifyEnabled. see http://stackoverflow.com/a/27052851/3184778

Answer (score 41):

NB.: Now instead of

```
runProguard false
```

you'll need to use

```
minifyEnabled false
```

Comment: guess it should be sets to true

Answer (score 3):

Here is Some of Most Common Proguard Rules that you need to add in **proguard-rules.pro** file in Android Sutdio.

**ButterKnife**

```
 -keep class butterknife.** { *; }
 -dontwarn butterknife.internal.**
 -keep class **$$ViewBinder { *; }
 -keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
        @butterknife.* <fields>;
  }
 -keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
        @butterknife.* <methods>;
  }
```

**Retrofit**

```
 -dontwarn retrofit.**
 -keep class retrofit.** { *; }
 -keepattributes Signature
 -keepattributes Exceptions
```

**OkHttp3**

```
 -keepattributes Signature
 -keepattributes *Annotation*
 -keep class okhttp3.** { *; }
 -keep interface okhttp3.** { *; }
 -dontwarn okhttp3.** 
 -keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
 -dontwarn java.nio.file.*
 -dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
```

**Gson**

```
 -keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
 -keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }
```

**Code obfuscation**

```
-keepclassmembers class com.yourname.models** { <fields>; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try renaming your 'proguard-rules.txt' file to 'proguard-android.txt' and remove the reference to 'proguard-rules.txt' in your gradle file. The `getDefaultProguardFile(...)` call references a different default proguard file, one provided by Google and not that in your project. So remove this as well, so that here the gradle file reads:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard true
        proguardFile 'proguard-android.txt'
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't work for me. I put my custom proguard-android.txt in the same directory by proguard-rules.txt, but nothing has changed in my code.

Comment: Thank you. 10 years later, this answer is what finally ended hours of troubleshooting for me for a Flutter project that wasn't generating the proguard file when I tried it the way stated in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers here are great references on using proguard. However, I haven't seen an issue discussed that I ran into that was a mind bender. After you generate a signed release .apk, it's put in the `/release` folder in your app but my app had an apk that wasn't in the `/release` folder. Hence, I spent hours decompiling the wrong apk wondering why my proguard changes were having no affect. Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

**Enable ProGuard**

[[ProGuard flow]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59285427/4770877)

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

[[ProGuard artefact]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59236358/4770877)