# APK size is bigger than expected - android studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, apk, android-gradle-plugin

My project content size like this,

1. Main Project (Source & asset size 513KB)
2. Module 1 (Source & asset size 135KB)
3. Module 2 (Source & asset size 80KB)

And the apk (signed, debug both) size is 4.87MB. Also tried ProGuard nothing changed.

I do not understand the reason of this. Even I have not added any jar file to my project.

Comment: http://developer.sonymobile.com/2012/01/31/tips-for-reducing-apk-file-size/
Refer this blog it may help you to reduce your android application size

Comment: Did you check what's inside the apk archive? Maybe there's some unwanted stuff (cache, backup, hidden files, etc) got included.

Comment: @asish were you able to figure this out ?

Comment: @Shobhit Nop, it is still a mystery to me.

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 build variants, for Debug and for Release. Default build option is for Debug which makes size big.

> Check this answer : 
>   [How to use the ProGuard in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20885725/how-to-use-the-proguard-in-android-studio/20888476#20888476)

Answer (score 2):

Clear the project and build again. Check raw, asset folder.

Give a look at this http://developer.android.com/tools/building/index.html .

Answer (score 1):

In case of a large png files existed try to enable the AAPT and use the next:

```
android {
    …
    buildTypes {
        release {
            crunchPngs true // or false
        }
    }
}
```