# Differences of Android apk exported by Eclipse and Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, build, apk

What are the differences of apk from Eclipse and Android Studio[IntelliJ IDEA]
is there more security in Android Studio build?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Android Studio utilizes the fast growing Gradle build system**. It builds on top of the concepts of Apache Ant and Apache Maven but it also introduces a `Groovy DSL (Domain-Specific Language)` that allows for scripted builds which opens up many automation possibilities like uploading your beta ***.apk to TestFlight for testing***.

**Eclipse** on the other hand uses Apache Ant as its main build system which a very *robust XML based build system* .

Please check this SO Answer

> [ADT (Eclipse) vs. Android Studio: How much APK file size difference is normal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24366944/adt-eclipse-vs-android-studio-how-much-apk-file-size-difference-is-normal)

### Conclusion

Both are identical.But i prefer **Android Studio**.

Comment: https://infinum.co/the-capsized-eight/articles/eclipse-is-dead-for-android-development-and-i-helped-kill-it

Answer (score 2):

They both use the Android SDK to generate the APKs, they should be identical.

Answer (score 2):

Code protection (security by obfuscation) is done with ProGuard both on Android Studio and on ADT (Eclipse). So if you use ProGuard, there should be no difference.