# Proguard-rules file missing from android studio project

Tags: android, eclipse, android-proguard

I started working on an android project in Eclipse. Now am working on 
the project using Android Studio. This project includes the Proguard files 
from the Eclipse configuration not the Android Studio configuration Proguard files. The files I have are Proguard-Project and a project file which tells me to uncomment some line to allow Proguard on my project. I don't have the proguard-rules.pro file which is the one needed to build project with proguard on studio. I've checked other projects that I started on android studio and they all have the proguard-rules.pro file. So, any advice how to enable proguard in this project that started in Eclipse and now is on Studio?
I have just updated my Android Studio to 1.2.2 but haven't run my app on my testing device yet from this new updated Android Studio.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use the ProGuard in Android Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20885725/how-to-use-the-proguard-in-android-studio)

Comment: my project doesn't include the proguard-rules file so therefore I cant customize my configurations for proguard according to android studio