# DexOverflowException after adding com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.4.2

Tags: android, firebase, dex, google-cloud-firestore

I have a problem after adding compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.4.2" to my build.

As soon as I add that, it also adds com.google.common among other things to my dex file, which is around 27k extra references, thus bursting through the 64k dex limit.

Does anyone know why that is or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 7):

Try adding these lines to your `build.gradle`

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 21 
        targetSdkVersion 26
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}
```

This will enable multidex mode, which will allow you to exceed the 64k limit. (Read more [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html))

## API below 21

If you're using an API level below 21, then you also need to add the support library

gradle.build:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

android.manafest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapp">
    <application
            android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" >
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

If you use a custom `Application` class, try using one the of the following

### Solution 1

simply override the MultiDexApplication class

```
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication { ... }
```

### Solution 2

override `attachBaseContext` and install MultiDex using the `install(Application)` function

```
public class MyApplication extends SomeOtherApplication {
  @Override
  protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
     super.attachBaseContext(base);
     MultiDex.install(this);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're not doing anything wrong: the Android API for Cloud Firestore is just big. We'll be working on reducing SDK size on the road to GA.

Meanwhile, you need to [enable multidex](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html) to build if your application is nontrivial.

We actually use very little of com.google.common, so you may be able to say under the 64k method limit by [proguarding your application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20885725/how-to-use-the-proguard-in-android-studio) too.

Answer (score 1):

Updating to 11.6.0 fixes this issue