# is app-debug.apk the application actual size?

Tags: android, android-studio

my question is about the file generated by going to `build` then `build (APKS)` and `locating` the file , getting an `app-debug.apk` is that the actual size of my app?

After going through this process i found that my application is 7MB is that good enough?

Comment: The final .apk file size is the size the user need to download, yes. Here are some infos how to reduce the apk file size: https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/reduce-apk-size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 build variants which are `debug` and `release`. Default build option is set to `debug` and usually has bigger size. To build `release` variant and reduce APK size you can use `ProGuard` and set `minifyEnabled` to `true` in `build.gradle`. To read more about using ProGuard visit link below:

[How to use the ProGuard in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20885725/how-to-use-the-proguard-in-android-studio/20888476#20888476)

To find some ProGuard rules visit this link:

[android-proguard-snippets](https://github.com/krschultz/android-proguard-snippets)

Some other useful articles in android developer website:

[Configure build variants](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants)

[Sign your app](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing)