# When I made minifyEnabled = true the app not working with API

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a big problem and I didn't find any solution for solve it first when I upload the app in the Google play I found this warning:

> There is no deobfuscation file associated with this App Bundle

After research I found the problem with mapping file and I `minifyEnabled = true` but when I added I found that problem `Missing class: org.conscrypt.ConscryptHostnameVerifier` and when I try open the app not working when I try call API not response any thing
and I searched a lot but without any benefit and I found all of solution but didn't success any solution with me. Anybody has a solution ?

**Edit 1:**

When I debug the error I found that error "Parameter specified as non-null is null: method j.u.b.g.e, parameter message" in that method

```java
protected fun <T> withLiveData(liveData: APILiveData<T>): SingleObserver<DataWrapper<T>> {
    return object : SingleObserver<DataWrapper<T>> {
        override fun onError(e: Throwable) {}
        override fun onSuccess(t: DataWrapper<T>) = liveData.postValue(t)
        override fun onSubscribe(d: Disposable) {
            compositeDisposable.add(d)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When I debug the error I found that error "Parameter specified as non-null is null: method j.u.b.g.e, parameter message "

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of search and a lot of try I found the problem but it is very difficult when I put minifyEnabled = true as I mentioned I found there are a lot of classes deleted and that need to me I go to all project  step by step check is that class deleted or not and If deleted must put in a file progaurd-rules.pro same that way

```
-keepclassmembers class  io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers{
                                                      public *;
                                                   }
```

but that will take a lot of times.

Comment: Thanks. Out of all solutions I searched, only this one worked for me.
I used:
-keepclassmembers class  com.example.** {
    public *;
  }

Answer (score 0):

Adding `minifyEnabled true` will obfuscate your code. It is a security measure to ensure that the code written cannot be read by reverse-engineering the compiled app. But it will mess up all your app if you haven't added the proper `ProGuard` rules.

You can build the app with `minifyEnabled false` and upload the bundle to Play and ignore the warning for now. But start searching on "Android Obfuscation".

[Shrink, obfuscate, and optimize your app](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add ProGuard rules. when you set minifyEnabled true, It detects any code or libraries that aren't being used and ignores them from your final apk/aab. So you should add data classes of your model to ProGuard.
Check this [Common Proguard Rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57157157/6166210)

Comment: Yah, already I put this classs org.conscrypt.ConscryptHostnameVerifier in ProGurad but still the app don't call any API